# JSON calls to an IIS server return 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, wordpress, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have IIS 7.5 setup with an wordpress site.  I have created a virtual directory (and it made into a web application) to setup a MVC4 website.  basically the main site (www.example.com) is the wordpress site and when link is clicked (www.example.com/order) then the order link points to the  mvc4 site.
I have a few JSON calls on the MVC4 and I'm getting Forbidden on all of those calls.
any ideas on why this is happening?  it is not a cross-origin problem.

Comment: You might need to set a user agent before making the request. Can you show some code making the request ?

Comment: By "JSON calls" I'm assuming you mean AJAX calls that receive and/or return JSON?

Comment: You need to post the code for your RouteConfig, your Controller/Action implementation, and the AJAX call itself.

Comment: just a basic jquery json call: $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetProducts","Home")", function (d) {});

Comment: It is the default RouteConfig for MVC4.  the JSON method is the following: public JsonResult GetProducts(){ return Json("{data}", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet}

Comment: I tried putting the website by itself (on a different port) and it worked just fine.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that whatever request made to `www.xxx.com/order` goes to your MVC4 website? How is this achieved?

Answer (score 1):

If you have, in your controller, something like this:

```
return Json("Foo");
```

replace it, with something like this:

```
return Json("Foo", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the IIS server's application settings to make sure the `Anonymous Authentication` is enabled. And disable all other Authentication module like the `Windows Authentication`.